# Objective-C Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Can anyone tell me why this is method is giving me leaks?  I've been looking at it for ages and can't figure out why its leaking.  The leaked object is `ContactOperations`.  the EventType is Malloc and Release. I thought the `init` might be wrong?

**Contact Controller**

```
ContactOperations *contactOps = [[ContactOperations alloc] initWithDatabase:database];
if ([contactOps applicationIsOwner])
    [contactOps startOperations];    
[contactOps release];
```

Instruments says the alloc is giving me the leak...

**Contact Operations**

```
ContactOperations
- (id)initWithDatabase:(Database*)aDatabase
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        database = [aDatabase retain];
        parameter = [[Parameter alloc] init];
        parameter.database = aDatabase;
        //addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    }
    return(self);
}



-(void)dealloc
{
    [database release];   
    [parameter release];
    //CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried static analysis from inside Xcode?

Comment: Is `contactOps` retained somewhere in `-[ContactOperations startOperations]`? Other than that, there are no leaks in the code you posted.

Comment: Stupid question: does it still give the warning if you set `contactOps` to `nil` after the release? If not, you technically have an overreleased instance still reachable from your code.

Comment: @trojanfoe - static analysis doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Costique its not retained this is the only way its used.

Comment: @Monolo I dont get a warning if I set it to nil after I release it.  I'm not to usually to bad at fixing leaks but instruments is being vague about this one.  The method is being called by MBProgressHUD... Could the thread being messing about with the AddressBook code inside ContactOperastions Perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [database release];   
    [parameter release];
    //CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

You have forgotten `[super dealloc];` at the end of `- (void) dealloc`. You have to call `[super dealloc]` in order to clear instance variables of ContactOperations' superclass.

Comment: Right. This is required when using reference counting instead of the garbage collector.

Comment: I'm so emabrassed and greatful all in one.  I have wasted hours on this.